# React Router: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a normal react app, using react router. When trying to get the url params in Box.js, I get this error: **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**
This is the code:

**Box.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Box()
{
    let params = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{params}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Box();
```

**App.js**

```
import
{
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Box from './Box';
function App()
{
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/palette/:id/:color" element={<Box />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what is the `export default Box()`? it should be without the practices

Comment: Voting to close as typo. `export default Box();` should be `export default Box;`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call a function while exporting.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Box()
{
    let params = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{params}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Box;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` from the export part

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Box(){
    let params = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{params}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Box;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm link or any other library, your bundler might see two different reacts and show that error [see here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react)

or you can remove the ()

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Box()
{
    let params = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{params}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Box();
```